# Unable to connect to Oracle database via RJDBC

Tags: r, rjdbc

I get an error when I try to make a connection to Oracle11G DB. My output is as below. Please advise

```
>Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45')
> options(java.parameters="-Xmx2g")
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
[1] 0
> print(.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.version"))
[1] "1.6.0_45"
> library(RJDBC)
> # Create connection driver and open connection
> jdbcDriver = JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="pathtofile/ojdbc6.jar")
> jdbcDriver
An object of class "JDBCDriver"
Slot "identifier.quote":
[1] NA

Slot "jdrv":
[1] "Java-Object{oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@9506dc4}"

> jdbcConnection = dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/servicename","username","password")
Error in dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/servicename",  : 
  unused arguments (jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/servicename", "username","password")
```

Comment: I've had this problem for quite some time and since my last comment, I did not revisit this issue until today. So here are the issues I had faced and the solutions to resolve them:                                                                                      1. Mismatch of the java bit versions against the R-GUI bit version.     Sol: I had uninstalled multiple java versions and made sure the JDK, R GUI and JDBC driver were compatible                                                     2. dbConnect () was masked by the '.GlobalEnv' object. To put it in scope as follows RJDBC::dbConnect()

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this the answer you are looking for, but this is how I make the connection:

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="pathtothisfile/ojdbc6.jar") 
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//Hostname:Port/SID", "username", "password")
```

Comment: I do the same. But I get the following message: Error in dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbcstring",  : 
  unused arguments (jdbcDriver, "jdbcstring", "user", "passwd")

Comment: Strange, I can't fugure out what's going on here. It seems an error in the jdbcstring. Are you sure you use the right hostname?

Comment: Yes. Very certain. Can you send me your output for                  drv <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="pathtothisfile/ojdbc6.jar")

Comment: I've had this problem for along time and since my last comment, I did not revisit this issue until today. So here are the issues I had faced and solutions to resolve them:                                                                                      1. Mismatch of the java bit versions against the R bit version interface. Solution: I had uninstalled multiple java installations and made sure the JDK / R GUI and JDBC driver were compatible.